# Get Google+ Email without GET_CONTACTS Permission

Tags: android, permissions

as Google+ stated here https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/people#retrieve_profile_information_for_a_signed_in_user

> You can use the Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName method to get the user's email address that is associated with the connected account. You must declare the permission  in your AndroidManifest.xml to use this method.

to get user email after login you have to write this code

```
final String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(googleApiClient);
```

end most important write GET_CONTACTS Permission on your AndroidManifest file.
but when I try same scenario on UBER app I noticed that they don't ask about GET_CONTACTS Permission and also get user email as I see it on UBER Settings screen 
How I can get user Google+ email without asking user for GET_CONTACTS Permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the user iformation from Google API using the following code.For more details you can refer : https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/people#before_you_begin

```
GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
String personEmail = acct.getEmail();
String personId = acct.getId();
Uri personPhoto = acct.getPhotoUrl();
```

Comment: I'm trying it and I'll get back to you , thanks in advance.